# Remove a line from file that starts with a number in bash

Tags: regex, bash, csv, parsing, sed

I am trying to create a simple CSV editor in bash, 
and I struggle with removing a line. The user passes in the ID of
the line to remove (each row is defined with an ID as the first column).

This is an example file structure:

```
ID,Name,Surname
0,Mark,Twain
1,Cristopher,Jones
```

So, having the id saved as a variable and the file name in another variable (say its file.csv) I attempt to remove it from bash with this line:

```
read -p "Pass the object's ID: " idtoremove
fname=file.csv
sed -i -e "'/^$idtoremove*,/d'" $fname
```

However, this has no effect on the file. What could be wrong with this line?

Also, how can I replace a line starting with given ID with a string from a variable? This is another problem I will have to face but I have no Idea how to approach this one.

Comment: Why are you using both double and single quotes around the `sed` command? Doesn't that cause `sed` to fail with an error message?

Comment: And what is the purpose of the `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script could help you. It asks user to enter an id.

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Please enter the id to be removed:"
read value
awk -v val="$value" -F, '$1!=val'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself append `> tmp_file && mv tmp_file Input_file` in above `awk` code.

***With*** `sed`***:***

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Please enter the id to be removed:"
read value
sed  "/^$value,/d"  Input_file
```

Kindly use `sed -i.bak` option in above `sed` to save output into Input_file itself and have a backup of Input_file(before change) too.

Comment: @anubhava, great catch sir, done that now. Thanks anubhava sir, cheers :)

Comment: Why you say -p is for password ? man dash tell me: The prompt is printed if the -p option is specified and the standard input is a terminal.  Then a line is read from the standard input.

Comment: @ctac_, thank you ctac, sorry I think I got confused with another option, I removed it, really thanks for your comment here.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done in `awk`:

```
awk -v id="$idtoremove" -F, '$1 != id' file.csv
```

If you're using `gnu awk` then you can save in-place also:

```
awk -i inplace -v id="$idtoremove" -F, '$1 != id' file.csv
```

For other `awk` versions use:

```
awk -v id="$idtoremove" -F, '$1 != id' file.csv > $$.csv &&
mv $$.csv file.csv
```